# Correctly read and edit a csv file containing encoded HTML and HTML encoded special chars

Tags: php, html, encoding, fgetcsv

I am currently facing a problem using fgetcsv when reading a CSV file containing HTML encoded special chars and html content. Regulary the file is delimited by semicolon but it contains HTML Content with semicolons too. EXCEL and any web-based CSV Viewer can read it but when using fgetcsv it does not find the correct end of a row.

File example:

```
1234;Example Text like gr&uuml;;<p style ="none;">this is html</p>;
```

Code example:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'de_DE.UTF-8');
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');

file_put_contents("./test_tmp.csv", fopen("https://xxx/test.csv", 'r'));

$input = fopen("./test_tmp.csv", 'r');  //open for reading
$output = fopen("./test.csv", 'w'); //open for writing

// <<- I guess the csv file needs to be decoded before fgetcsv reads 
// so it gets correctly delimited
while( false !== ( $data = fgetcsv($input,0,';'))){  //read each line as an array

fputs($output, implode($data)."\n");
}

//close both files
fclose( $input );
fclose( $output );
```

Does anyone know a solution?

Comment: I can't solve this but have a look at this user contributed note in the manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php#88616 could help. See if error reporting helps http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: Maybe just pull the file in, decode the entities, then use the `str_getcsv`. The values of the CSV are not encapsulated though? That seems like a CSV creation issue.

Comment: I already thought about decoding everything and then putting it back into a CSV. Unfortunatly i haven't found a way to write it back exactly the same way. The funny thing about it is, that every CSV reader accepts this CSV just PHP seems to have problems with encoded CSV files.. any other suggestions?